# Calling async method inside a Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Let's say I have an async method such as:

```
public async Task<int> HeavyWork()
{
    return Task.Run( () => { //some heavy work } );
}
```

Let's say I put this task inside another Task by adding it to a queue:

```
...
QueueTask(new Task( () => { HeavyWork(); } ));
...
```

Suppose the method QueueTask simply takes a task and starts it and wait until it finished then it moves on to the next task ... starting the task that's got "HeavyWork()" in it ... will it return right away since it is async?

Comment: If you do not use `await` on a Task, the calling function will continue to execute and the Task will run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` and `await` keywords work in concert to allow a method to return before it's completed and then to continue executing at a later time.

It is not possible to explain precisely what happens in your scenario, because very little of the actual code is shown in your question. Taken literally, your `HeavyWork()` method need not be `async` at all, because there is no `await` used in it.

In other words, `async` only allows `await`; it doesn't affect the behavior of the method at all. If you never use `await` in the method, then the method will run synchronously, not returning until it has completed whatever its work is.

In that case, you add the `Task` object to your queue, the queue starts the task, the task invokes the anonymous method which in turn calls `HeavyWork()`, and the task doesn't complete until the `HeavyWork()` method returns, allowing the anonymous method to return.

That's not very interesting, so let's assume somewhere in `HeavyWork()`, you actually *do* use `await`. In that case, the `HeavyWork()` method will return before it has completed executing, at the point where the `await` happens (i.e. after whatever is being awaited has returned its awaitable object — usually this is a `Task` object — and before anything after the `await`).

As far as the `Task` which you've queued is concerned, *that* is the completion of the call to `HeavyWork()`. So the queued task will complete before the `HeavyWork()` method has actually completed executing. Note that this isn't necessarily right away; any code before the first `await` will be executed before `HeavyWork()` returns.

Note that in this second scenario, if you want to know when the `HeavyWork()` method has completed, you need to observe the returned `Task` somehow. Typically, this would be done with `await`, `Task.WhenAll()` (for a collection of `Task` objects), or similar mechanisms.

One possible approach, since your task queue is (as you say) waiting synchronously for each task to complete (not necessarily the best design, but let's assume for the moment there's a good reason for it here), you could have it check each task before trying to start it, and only starting it if it hasn't been already (attempting to start an already-started task will result in an exception being thrown).

In that case, you could just pass the return value of the `HeavyWork()` method itself to the queue:

```
QueueTask(HeavyWork());
```

Then, `HeavyWork()` would execute up to the first `await` (presumably something that would be relatively quick, since the whole reason to make the method `async` is so you move long-running work to happen asynchronously), and then would return a `Task` object that represents the work of the whole method.

The queue would, on dequeueing that particular `Task` object, note that it had already started and simply wait for it to complete. When the `HeavyWork()` method finally finishes *all* of its work and a result is available, the queue would see its wait complete and would proceed, just as if it had been passed a `Task` wrapper around some synchronous method.

Note that all of the above is necessarily vague and hypothetical. It's impossible to provide specific advice, given the vagueness of the original question. But I hope this helps clarify how `async` and `await` work together, and in particular how they would work in the vaguely-stated scenario you describe.